# With Python through XML lists and convert to dict

Tags: python, xml, list, dictionary

I have an xml file looking like this, but just much more managedObjects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2017-02-04T12:17:29" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="C" version="R1" KName="PP-1" id="269">
      <p name="aC">0</p>
      <p name="bC">3</p>
      <p name="cC">2</p>
      <list name="dC">
        <item>
          <p name="eC">2</p>
          <p name="fC">2</p>
        </item>
        <item>
          <p name="gC">14</p>
          <p name="hC">45</p>
        </item>
      <p name="iC">5</p>
      <p name="jC">15</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="C" version="R1" KName="PP-2" id="270">
      <p name="aC">23</p>
      <p name="bC">2</p>
      <p name="cC">2</p>
      <list name="dC">
        <item>
          <p name="eC">2</p>
          <p name="fC">3</p>
        </item>
        <item>
          <p name="gC">14</p>
          <p name="hC">54</p>
        </item>
      <p name="iC">5</p>
      <p name="jC">15</p>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

The way I've parsed this xml into the dictionary so I could compare values of parameters with each other:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('my_xml.xml').getroot()

temp_C = []

for atype in list(e):
    for i in list(atype):
        if i.get('class') == 'C':
            temp_C.append(i)
temp = []
for i in temp_C:
    for j, k in zip(list(i), i):
        temp.append([i.get('KName'), j.get('name'), j.text])

tempdict = {}

for i in temp_C:
    td = {}
    for j in list(i):
        td.update({j.get('name'): j.text})
    tempdict.update({i.get('KName'): td})
    for j in list(i):
        td.update({j.get('name'): j.text})

#Next part of code it's part where problem is:

        if j.get('name') == 'dC':
            elementi_itema = []
            for item in list(j):
                lista_name = {}
                for w in list(item):
                    lista_name.update({w.get('name'): w.text})
                elementi_itema.append(lista_name)

            td.update({'dC': elementi_itema})

        tempdict.update({i.get('KName'): td})
```

And this works perfectly, put list values in some python list and that is value of "dC" key in inner dictionary, but the problem is that I have in other xmls another name of lists or in the same xml more different lists, not the always "dC", so I need some universal solution that will work on every list inside xml tree, not depending on list name.

Comment: why not get all `<list>`'s in the file (`root.findall("list")`) and loop over all their children? If you want to compare specific values you could make your code into a function and have their names as parameters

Comment: @M.T I have tried something similiar, but it's not working, I'm not sure where my mistakes is.

Comment: Can you share code of what you have tried regarding M.T's suggestion?